# PHP - remove line from a file pointer

Tags: php, file, pointers

How can I **remove a line from a file pointer** in PHP?
I open the file using `fgets()` and not with `file()` because the file is too big.

The actual problem is: I have **2 very big files**. I need to **remove all lines from file 1 which exist in file 2**.

This is the code:

```
$handle1 = fopen("1.txt", "r+");
$handle2 = fopen("2.txt", "r");

if ($handle2) {
    while (!feof($handle2)) {
        $buffer2 = trim(fgets($handle2));

            if ($handle1) {
                while (!feof($handle1)) {
                    $buffer1 = trim(fgets($handle1));
                    if($buffer1 == $buffer2)
                        // stuck here
                }
                fclose($handle1);
            }

    }
    fclose($handle2);
}
```

How the line can be removed?

Thanks!

Comment: 2 while loops at once. I scream. How big are your very big files?

Comment: They do not fit in the memory. Big enough?

Comment: No that is not big enough since your memory could be not big enough.

Comment: You logic is all out of whack. You close `$handle1` in the first iteration of the outer loop... what do you think will happen on consecutive iterations?

Comment: You are right, my bad. Should be closed at the end. Corrected. Anyway, I do not know how to remove line from file pointer.

Comment: You cannot insert lines into a file arbitrarily. The best solution is to simply write to a new file and then replace the old file.

Comment: I think your best option would be to write what you want to end up with to a new file as opposed to trying to edit the file line by line.